# Using Maybe with State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm trying to implement a FIFO Queue in Haskell with push/pop/peek operations, and this is what I got so far.

```
data Queue a = Queue { 
  inbox :: [a], 
  outbox :: [a] 
} deriving (Eq, Show)

push :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
push e (Queue inb out) = Queue (e:inb) out

pop :: Queue a -> (Maybe a, Queue a)
pop q = 
  case top of
    Nothing   -> (top, emptyQueue)
    Just elem -> (Just elem, poppedQueue)
    where
      (top, q') = peek q
      poppedQueue = Queue (inbox q') (tail $ outbox q')

peek :: Queue a -> (Maybe a, Queue a)
peek q@(Queue [] [])    = (Nothing, emptyQueue)
peek q@(Queue inb [])   = peek $ Queue [] (reverse inb)
peek q@(Queue _ outb)   = (Just $ head outb, q)

emptyQueue = Queue [] []
```

So the above works, and I can push/pop/peek at my Queue. As you see, I wrapped up the return type in a Maybe, so that I get a Nothing if I pop an empty queue or peek at an empty queue, and a Just element otherwise.

So I also thought I could use the State monad to easily chain operations. I proceeded as follows:

```
type QueueState a = State (Queue a)

pushQueue :: a -> QueueState a ()
pushQueue e = state $ \q -> ((),push e q)

popQueue :: QueueState a (Maybe a)
popQueue = state $ \q -> pop q
```

Allright, so that seems to work. I can do:

```
runState (pushQueue 2 >> pushQueue 3 >> popQueue >> pushQueue 1 >> popQueue) emptyQueue
```

and get back `(Just 3,Queue {inbox = [1], outbox = []})`, which is what I wanted. But I can't do something like:

```
runState (pushQueue 2 >> popQueue >>= pushQueue) emptyQueue
```

which results in an:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = Maybe a0
Expected type: Maybe a0
               -> StateT (Queue a0) Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ()
  Actual type: Maybe a0 -> QueueState (Maybe a0) ()
```

Now I think I understand why that this, but I can't figure out how to make it do what I want. That is, a chaining using `>>=` from a `pop` should be able to feed into a `push`. I'm thinking I might need to use a StateT transformer, but I don't really understand them yet, so I'm looking for help on how do implement that functionality. Or do I need to do this in a completely different way? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with monad transformers to really answer, but it sounds like a task for either the `StateT` or `MaybeT` transformer. Kleisli arrows might be useful too.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the compiler can not construct an infinite type ;-).

More helpfully, consider the line:

```
runState (pushQueue 2 >> popQueue >>= pushQueue) emptyQueue
```

What is the type of `popQueue`?  `QueueState Int (Maybe Int)`.   (think `m (Maybe Int)`)

What is the type of `>>= pushQueue`?  `QueueState Int Int -> QueueState Int ()`    (think `m Int -> m ()`)

So the typechecker tries to unify the types `Maybe a` and `a` - the only way those types unify is if `a` if an infinite type of `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe ...`.

The solution is to do *something* to handle the `Nothing` case.  For example, `return ()` or push depending on the Maybe.

```
runState (pushQueue 2 >> popQueue >>= maybe (return ()) pushQueue) emptyQueue
```

Comment: Thanks, the explanation for the occurs check makes sense. But is this really how I would go about doing this? It looks 'hacky'. I thought the point of all this `>>=` stuff is to hide away such complexities. Is there no way to somehow go 'inside' `m`, and use monad rules for `Maybe` to apply a `m (Maybe a)` value to a function of type `a -> m b`, so that my original example just works? Just trying to learn monads well :)

Comment: No, monadic bind is not intended to / can not provide conversion from arbitrary types into a desired input type... no matter how trivial or common the type.